# How to sign with silverlight a database registry

Tags: c#, silverlight, digital-signature, xml-dsig

I have my key pair in Silverlight client and I want to sign a database registry. Is this possible? What kind of XML will I generate? Detached, enveloped, enveloping?

I tried an example  I found on the internet but it uses the System.Cryptography namespace to sign and create the XMLDSig but the namespace is not valid in Silvelight. I don't want to use other libraries like Chilkat or Blackbox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "database registry"? Do you mean a value that will be stored in a database? Do you mean a registry key that stores database connection information?

Comment: Is a value stored in a database with the data information.